# Disable zooming in a scrollview while I'm doing something else

Tags: ios, scrollview, zooming

I'll explain: I have a UIWebView with its Scrollview. I want that the user can scroll and zoom; but when he presses a button (that I implemented) I want that my scrollview is locked: no scroll, no zoom.

To disable scroll there is this easy function:

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

My question is: is there a similar function to disable zoom? And if not, why in the world there isn't a similar function to disable zoom? And what can I do instead?
Thank you all.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561521/turn-off-zooming-in-uiscrollview

Comment: Is that the only way? Very ugly.

Comment: iOS5+: scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO; I'd say that is quite pretty :)

Comment: It's very pretty, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for disable scroll and zoom in webview .

```
_webview_info.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;
```

Hope this code useful for you.

Comment: Best way to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions I found worked for my exact case, so I tried removing the pinch recognizer from the gestureRecognizers array on my scroll view.

First I grabbed a reference to the pinch recognizer:

```
for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in scrollView.gestureRecognizers){
    if([gesture isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]){
        pinchZoomGestureRecognizer = gesture;
    }
}
```

Then I used the following method to add/remove the gesture from the scrollview

```
-(void)setScrollViewZoomEnabled:(BOOL)enabled{
    NSMutableArray *gestures = [scrollView.gestureRecognizers mutableCopy];

    if(enabled){
        [gestures addObject:pinchZoomGestureRecognizer];
    }else{
        [gestures removeObject:pinchZoomGestureRecognizer];
    }

    scrollView.gestureRecognizers = gestures;
}
```

This is working for me on iOS 8 - 10.  Hopefully this isn't a duplicate.