# Disable zoom in/out on wkwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I want to disable the zoom in and out on a wkwebview which contain an iframe 
I tried

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" >
```

on my website but it didn't work . Any suggestion?

Comment: This question is already answered. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31943976/7220486

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. From this gist https://gist.github.com/paulofierro/66aea963303df735aa00

```
// Remember to @import WebKit at the top of the class

// Javascript that disables pinch-to-zoom by inserting the HTML viewport meta tag into <head>
NSString *source = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); \
meta.name = 'viewport'; \
meta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'; \
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];\
head.appendChild(meta);";
WKUserScript *script = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:source injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];

// Create the user content controller and add the script to it
WKUserContentController *userContentController = [WKUserContentController new];
[userContentController addUserScript:script];

// Create the configuration with the user content controller
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [WKWebViewConfiguration new];
configuration.userContentController = userContentController;

// Create the web view with the configuration
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:configuration];
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:webView];

// Add the constraints
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(webView);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[webView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[webView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"]]];
```