# WKWebView pinch-to-zoom in iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, ios10

I encountered a problem that after I upgraded my phone to iOS 10 beta 3, when I zoom a WKWebView in my app, the zooming function not only zoom the content of the web page but also the page itself.

See the image I attached. [WKWebView that fails to zoom correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgwyY.jpg) I set the background color of the WKWebView to blue, when I pinch to zoom out the view, the page(container?) itself also zoomed out, causing unfavorable result. **It does not happen in iOS9.** When I do the same thing, the blue background does not show.
The web page is written in `AngularJS` and the Graph **lib** is `d3js`.

The related code are as below.

```
-(void) reloadWebPage{
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    NSString *indexToPath = [self getIndexHtmlPath];
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:indexToPath];
    NSURL *absoluteUrl = fileUrl.absoluteURL;
    if(currentGroup == nil){
        currentGroup = @"0";
    }
    NSString *absoluteString = [[absoluteUrl absoluteString] stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", @"?currentGroup=", currentGroup];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:absoluteString] ];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

}

- (void)createWebView{

    WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    [config.userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"interOp"];
    webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:config];
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [webView setNavigationDelegate:self];
    [webView setUIDelegate:self];
}
```

I have no clue where is the problem? Is it in Objective C,iOS10 or in Javascript?
Please suggest, How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable viewport zooming iOS 10 safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari)

Comment: The link you mentioned intended to disable zooming, I don't want to disable it. Besides, I didn't use `user-scalable=no` either.

Comment: Ok, I got it. May be you can give a link with problem page?

Comment: Yes, I did. Please see the link "WKWebView that fails to zoom correctly." in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved this problem by disabling zooming and scrolling in `WKWebView`.

`webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;`

`- (UIView*) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return nil;
}`

After these code are added, the `WKWebView` itself no longer zooming and moving while the nodes move and zoom normally.

It seems the problem somewhat related to [Disable magnification gesture in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553711/disable-magnification-gesture-in-wkwebview?noredirect=1&lq=1), but
I still don't know what caused the change from iOS9 to iOS10. But it seems to work for me.