# Disable zoom in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

Does anyone know a nice simple way to disable double-click and pinch zooming in a WKWebView? Nothing I've tried works:

```
Webview.scrollView.allowsMagnification = false;    // Error: value of type WKWebView has no member allowsMagnification

Webview.scrollView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false; // doesn't do anything
```

In the html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" /> // pile of crap, does nothing
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You will have to add maximum scale in script.

The following code should help you:

```
let source: String = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');" +
    "meta.name = 'viewport';" +
    "meta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no';" +
    "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];" +
    "head.appendChild(meta);"

let script: WKUserScript = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
let userContentController: WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
let conf = WKWebViewConfiguration()
conf.userContentController = userContentController
userContentController.addUserScript(script)
let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: conf)
```

Comment: If you already have a webView instance, simply replace the last 5 lines with `webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)`

Comment: This script worked whereas the equivalent script in [this article](https://medium.com/@maxcampolo/making-javascript-feel-like-native-ios-with-wkwebview-d92dfefe8d56) did not.  That article is still worth the read, however.

Comment: This works on iOS 12. As expected, neither double tap nor pinch zoom the content.

Comment: This javascript will not work when load file path url. Please help me if you have any soltuion.

Comment: Your solution not work for given url http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf . Please help me if you have any solution.

Comment: I was loading data from a local html to WKWebView so I added the code of scaling directly to the html and it worked great..thanks for the answer

Comment: I actually just called *evaluateJavaScript* on the string and that works.

Comment: I had to simplify the content variable, leaving only user-scalable=no, and it worked well for me like that

Comment: this also helps to disable the auto-zoom when keyboard appears.

Answer (score 24):

OK this is how I solved this:

```
wkWebView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(self.getZoomDisableScript()) 

private func getZoomDisableScript() -> WKUserScript {
    let source: String = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');" +
        "meta.name = 'viewport';" +
        "meta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no';" +
        "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];" + "head.appendChild(meta);"
    return WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
}
```

Comment: YEAH! No probs Awais!

Comment: @DroidChris above solution not work for given url http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf . Please help me if you have any solution.

Comment: @YogendraPatel, the solution will only work for websites.

Comment: This is Javascript injection so it is a website specific thing. You are trying to do PDFs? Last time I worked with PDFs in iOS was around 2015 and you do not need a Webview to use them. @YogendraPatel please look into PDFKit framework.

Comment: This is the only solution that actually disabled zoom on double-tap in iOS 14

Comment: @NIK yeah glad to hear! And glad that it still works in IOS 14.

Answer (score 22):

Swift 4:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self
}

//MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate
func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?) {
         scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: This worked out perfectly for me, however double tap zooming is still enabled and I haven't found a good way to remove it.

Comment: Breaks in ios 12

Comment: Not quite working. The Webview zooms in when the user focuses a text field. And then the user has no way of zooming out...

Comment: @DanielS have you find any solution for double tap?

Comment: Doesn't disable zoom on double tap in iOS 14

Answer (score 7):

**Solution 1 for web pages**

This post explains how managing the zoom.

[WebKit: New Interaction Behaviors in iOS 10](https://webkit.org/blog/7367/new-interaction-behaviors-in-ios-10/)

In iOS 10 ["ignoresViewportScaleLimits" property was added to WKWebViewConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/2274633-ignoresviewportscalelimits), which is false by default. The post recommends to set to true and to manage correctly the zoom in the page.

Note: In Safari and SafariViewController the value for this property is true by default.

In my case I want to reset the zoom in some cases. For this the unique way that I found it was change maximum scale to 1.0 and after to 10.0.

```
NSString* js =
    @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); " \
    "meta.setAttribute( 'name', 'viewport' ); " \
    "meta.setAttribute( 'content', 'width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = yes' ); " \
    "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta)";
[_wkWebview evaluateJavaScript:js completionHandler:^(id _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSString* js =
    @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); " \
    "meta.setAttribute( 'name', 'viewport' ); " \
    "meta.setAttribute( 'content', 'width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 10.0, user-scalable = yes' ); " \
    "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta)";
    [_wkWebview evaluateJavaScript:js completionHandler:nil];
}];
```

This code should works but I recommend to create the "viewport" always in the html and to create a function (i.e. resetZoom or disableZoom) in the javascript to call it directly from objective-C (it is cleaner)

I hope it helps.

**Solution 2 for file URL**

Override scroll view delegate:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    
    init() {
        super.init()
        webView.scrollView.delegate = self
    }
    
    deinit() {
        // To prevent crash when ViewController is deinitialized
        webView.scrollView.delegate = nil
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution not work for given url http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf . Please help me if you have any solution.

Comment: That is true because that url is a file (pdf) not a web page so it has not HTML to be modified. You can try to override the scroll view delegate for this case, I have updated my answer, but I don't know if it will work.

Answer (score 3):

it's works on iOS 13

```
NSString *javascript = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";
// you should use WKUserScript, `evaluateJavaScript` is not working
WKUserScript *us = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:javascript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];[wkWebView.configuration.userContentController addUserScript:us];
```

not working

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return nil;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view {
    scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: Your solution not work for given url http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf . Please help me if you have any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't find a proper way to completely disable zooming by double tap, but here's a workaround that's sufficient for my use case:

```
private var zoomScale: CGFloat? = nil

func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?) {
    zoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale

    // And use the same solution to prevent pinch to zoom as in other answers
    scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
}
    
func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if let originalScale = zoomScale {
        scrollView.zoomScale = originalScale
    }
}
```

It simply stores the zoomScale before the zooming begins, and then resets it immediately after it finishes, resulting in just a little movement.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below code will fix all the zoom issue with WKWebView. This disables the zoom option of the scrollview and so there is no need to handle the scroll view delegates or tap delegates. One important point to note is to add this configuration in the **init of WKWebView**. Setting the config later to the wkwebview will not work.

```
let source: String = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');" + "meta.name = 'viewport';" + "meta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no';" + "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];" + "head.appendChild(meta);";
let script: WKUserScript = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
let userContentController: WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
let conf = WKWebViewConfiguration()
conf.userContentController = userContentController
userContentController.addUserScript(script)
        
webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration:conf)
```

Additionally you can add the below line of code to disable the vertical scroll of the webpage when any textfiled is clicked.

```
webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
private func getZoomDisableScript() -> WKUserScript {
    let source: String = """
        document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        },{passive: false});

        """
    return WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
}
```

and apply to webkit:

```
webKit.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(self.getZoomDisableScript())
```