# Hybrid Webview IOS stop zooming

Tags: ios, webview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am building an app using Xamarin Forms, in this I have implemented a hybrid webview. In IOS, hybrid web view is having zoom feature which I need to disaBLE it.

Here is what I tried so far:-

```
  public class ActivityHybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<ActivityHybridWebView, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
    {
        const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){window.webkit.messageHandlers.invokeAction.postMessage(data);}";
        WKUserContentController userController;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ActivityHybridWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                userController = new WKUserContentController();
                var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
                userController.AddUserScript(script);
                userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, "invokeAction");
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
                var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                webView.ScrollView.MultipleTouchEnabled = false;
                webView.ScrollView.Bounces = false;
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                Control.ScrollView.MultipleTouchEnabled = false;
                Control.ScrollView.Bounces = false;
                userController.RemoveAllUserScripts();
                userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler("invokeAction");
                var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as ActivityHybridWebView;
                hybridWebView.Cleanup();
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                string localpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                string url = Path.Combine(localpath, Element.Uri);
                Control.LoadFileUrl(new NSUrl("file://" + url), new NSUrl("file://" + Path.GetDirectoryName(url)));
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Task.WaitAny(Task.Delay(2000));
                    InjectJS(JavaScriptFunction);
                    CallJS();
                });

            }
        }
```

These two lines seems to have no effect-

```
Control.ScrollView.MultipleTouchEnabled = false;
Control.ScrollView.Bounces = false;

webView.ScrollView.MultipleTouchEnabled = false;
webView.MultipleTouchEnabled = false;
```

Comment: The webview should have some properties like minimum and maximum zoom level? Try setting them to the same level.

Comment: @Gerald Versluis i tried setting both to 1 then also no effect.

Comment: Can you change the website code? If yes, you could disable zooming there by adding the following tag inside html head: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

Comment: @hamalaiv using meta tag worked!

Comment: @hamalaiv Works fine! This should be the answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the website code? If yes, you could disable zooming there by adding the following tag inside html head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin: Disable zoom in iOS WKWebView

```
var source = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');" +
"meta.name = 'viewport';" +
"meta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no';" +
"var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];" + "head.appendChild(meta);";

var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(source), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, true);

wkWebView.Configuration.UserContentController.AddUserScript(script);
```

> source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41741125/546054