# How to set iOS WkWebview zoom scale

Tags: ios, wkwebview, zooming

My iOS app has a WKWebView component which shows an full-screen WebApp (1280x800) with different aspect ratio and size then a iPad (4:3, 1024x768)

I want to set the WkWebView zoom factor to 0.8, to fit it in landscape mode.
How can I control the zoom scale of the WkWebView?

I tried to set the the zoom scale of the WkWebView scrollview, but it doesn't scale for values below 1, even when I set the minimumZoomScale accordingly.

```
[self.webView.scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:0.8];

[self.webView.scrollView setZoomScale:0.8];
```

Does anyone have an idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: You might be able to do this by injecting js into the view, overriding html viewport tags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929673/1214800

Comment: Every browser has the possibility to zoom in/out, without affecting the original html/js. I'm looking for something similar with the WKWebView component. I succeeded with an Android/Windows app, but so far not with an iOS app. How can I zoom in/out programatically from the iOS native code?

Answer (score 30):

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=YES">` to your HTML file.

It works as if you used scalePageToFit in UIWebView.

Comment: This also helped me where a Vimeo video embedded in an iframe was showing much too small, as though it was zoomed out.