# Xamarin Forms Webview Disable zoom on IOS platform

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I have a webview project in Xamarin, it can zoom on IOS platform but I want to disable it

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

We have this tag in our HTML page, but it's still zoomable on IOS, how can I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code in the webview renderer on the ios:

```
var source = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');" +
"meta.name = 'viewport';" +
"meta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, 
user-scalable=no';" +
"var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];" + 
"head.appendChild(meta);";
var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(source), 
WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, true);
wkWebView.Configuration.UserContentController.AddUserScript(script);
```

And if you need more information, you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452034/disable-zoom-in-wkwebview/41741125#41741125) and [this one](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/111183).

Comment: Is this solution for xf and can you describe how I can apply it? 
When I checked the links you sent, I noticed that the solution in both links was swift.

Comment: You can try to put it in the ElementChanged event. @Arslan

Comment: Where exactly should I apply it, where I call the webview, there is no element changed event?

Comment: You need to use the custom render for the webview. And put the code in the OnElementChanged method in the ios part.@Arslan