# Objective-C Can't Find Instance Method of Imported WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, webkit, wkwebview

I am using a WKWebView and I am trying to set its magnification with the `setMagnification` instance method in a class that the webView is a variable of. Whenever I try to compile I get:

> No visible @interface for 'WKWebView' declares the selector 'setMagnification:centeredAt:'

despite the fact that WebKit is being imported.

```
-(void)zoomIn:(int) xCoord y:(int) yCoord
{
    CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(xCoord, yCoord);
    [_webView setMagnification:3 centeredAt:myPoint]
}
```

Edit:
Just learned why this does not work is because it is OSX only, and I need it for iOS.  If you have an alternative for iOS, please let me know.

Comment: This method is only available in OSX (Since 10.10, see the doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414996-setmagnification?language=objc) Are you building for iOS?

Comment: Oh, I just saw that.  I am using iOS.  Is there any alternative you know for it?

Comment: I don't know. But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553711/disable-magnification-gesture-in-wkwebview ? It's not the same goal (at all), but it reminds that `WKWebView` has a `scrollView` property. Maybe something to search there.