# WKWebView only vertical scroll & not horizontal scroll & not page zoom

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I want to have only vertical scroll on the site I show with WebView(WKWebView). I want to prevent zoom.

swift 4 / xcode 9.4

Comment: Set your content mode Aspect Fit.

Comment: Not worked (aspect fit).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable magnification gesture in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553711/disable-magnification-gesture-in-wkwebview)

Comment: I try but it did not happen.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way

```
 yourWebView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
 yourWebView.scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: I tried the same solution in my project and worked.